# The picture is getting cut when I put my ASC file of altitude variable

Tags: qgis, esri-ascii-raster

I am trying to project my ASC file of altitude variable on QGIS. But its picture is getting cut and a visual cuts and bruises are seen in the picture. Can you please tell me why is it happening?[image]

Comment: Just from the look of the scale (1:17 million) it seems a world map (usually 1:100 million will put the world onto A3 size paper). Then the map extent, which looks portrait, is weird... I am afraid you might have mistaken latitude with longitude. It probably makes unexpected reading order of ascii data columns/rows.

Comment: Hi, the raster for altitude has been clipped perfectly to my study sit and it is also projecting fine on QGIS. The only thing of bother is that when I am copying cell size and column size from my different set of bioclimatic variables (rasters) to ASC file of my altitude (raster) variable. This pixelated and bruised type of image is coming

Comment: can you add the top 5 or 6 lines of the asc file to your question